# Armadillo sparse allocation of a matrix

Tags: c++, matlab, armadillo

In Matlab, I allocate space for sparse matrix like this:

```
%Notice "Const_Block_Upper" is a dense matrix
%Number of nonzero element
nz = size(Const_Block_Upper,1)*size(Const_Block_Upper,2)*No_of_Voxels;
SizeR = No_of_Voxels*size(Const_Block_Upper,1)
SizeC = No_of_Voxels*size(Const_Block_Upper,2);

%Allocates space for sparse matrix of size (SizeR, SizeC) with atmost nz non-zeros
A = spalloc(SizeR, SizeC, nz);
```

I am wondering if I can do something similar in C++ lib Armadillo. I looked at documentation of Armadillo; however, could not find something similar.

Some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder at which part of the documentation you looked, because [the official documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#SpMat) contains a lot about the sparse matrix types. For example about batch insertion:

> Batch insertion constructors:
>
> ```
> form 1: sp_mat(locations, values, sort_locations = true)
> form 2: sp_mat(locations, values, n_rows, n_cols, sort_locations = true, check_for_zeros = true)
> form 3: sp_mat(add_values, locations, values, n_rows, n_cols, sort_locations = true, check_for_zeros = true)
> form 4: sp_mat(rowind, colptr, values, n_rows, n_cols)
> ```

EDIT: Ah, I understand your question now; you want to preallocate the space necessary for element storage; I'm afraid there's no possibility to do so with the underlying sparse matrix storage format...

Comment: I was searching for ways to allocate space for sparse matrix with maximum  number of nonzero element = nz.